# Which article about Esperanto has been most widely read?

Tags: culture

I have read a few articles about Esperanto written in major newspapers, but do we know which ones have had the most readers? Would that be in a newspaper or online somewhere? 
[This interview](https://amp.zdf.de/nachrichten/heute/tag-der-muttersprache-und-esperanto-100.html?fbclid=IwAR1me-JGgzvvCWIAtV4sm8qYbOtweIZCqS12M5CeHm970fTnFBT3EHfrkTU) was published for the day of the native language in German.

Comment: How would anybody know? Even the publisher of a newspaper can't tell, how many people read a specific article. It's almost the same problem with online articles. You never know, if a requested site is really read. There are lots of bots for all kind of purposes and you never know, what people actually do after opening a website. Maybe they just watch the pictures, maybe they just check for the way, a specific word is used in an article ...

Comment: This is an issue that everyone has, but the solution is simply to define what exactly is measured. How many issues were sold, how many visits did the webpage have? 
I don't see a problem writing that for answering the question.

Comment: Even if these numbers were known (and public, which they AFAIK don't tend to be) for _some_ articles, how would we know that there isn't any other article where they're even higher?

Comment: That's a silly counter-argument. I'm just looking for the best information we have, which can be improved with more information.

Comment: Publishers in fact could now, based on sales, pre-Internet days.  Now with newspapers published on the Internet, they have more data at hand and can know how many people read an article.  I'm not sure how much of this is publicly available and where to look for it...:(